# How to build parent POM and JAR within one pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, resources

I have two Maven projects, for example:

```
ProjectA
|- pom.xml (packaging="atlassian-plugin", or can be "jar")

ProjectB
|- pom.xml (packaging="pom")
|- src/main/resources
   |- templates
     |- file1.xml
   |- i18n.properties
   | ...
```

Now ProjectA got the ProjectB as parent declaration to get all the build, ... info from the `pom.xml` of ProjectB. If I build this ProjectB (`clean install`) I only get the build of the pom, because of `packaging="pom"`.

What I want now is, that if I run '`clean install`' on ProjectB, that the correct parent POM AND the correct JAR with all resources are build.

Still now I didn't use any kind of modules. Currently I have to switch the packaging mode and do `clean install` twice for ProjectB.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry for writing one of the "are you sure you really want to do this" comments, but ... usually a parent pom project contains just a pom.xml. I do not understand why your ProjectB is not just two projects, one with a parent pom and one that bundles the resources.

Comment: If you have to switch the packaging mode you are going the wrong path..furthermore I don't understand what the purpose of the pom is you wanted to build?